# CKAN Internal server error by adding ckanext-restricted plugin in my ckan.ini

Tags: command-line, extension

Hello I'm new at creating data systems using CKAN, I just want to know if i'm doing the exact thing.

I've found a repo extention in github `https://github.com/EnviDat/ckanext-restricted` and I want that to my system, I follow the steps in installing `ckanext-restricted` I put it in `. /usr/lib/ckan/default/src` and type

```
git clone https://github.com/espona/ckanext-restricted.git
cd ckanext-restricted
python setup.py develop
pip install -r dev-requirements.txt
```

and I added restricted in `ckan.plugins` in my
`/etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini` and when a restart my system by typing `sudo supervisorctl reload` then `sudo supervisorctl status`

and the status look like below

```
ckan-datapusher:ckan-datapusher-00   RUNNING   pid 15888, uptime 0:23:24
ckan-uwsgi:ckan-uwsgi-00             RUNNING   pid 15889, uptime 0:23:24
ckan-worker:ckan-worker-00 FATAL Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

and when a refresh my system it's say "Internal server error". I'm really stock, I'm a newbie in CKAN. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909842/supervisor-fatal-exited-too-quickly-process-log-may-have-details ?

Comment: Thankyou for your response @Liso . I've read the problem and their solution. In my case when I added restricted in ckan.plugin in my ini file the error will occur. I didn't know why but I just followed their documentation https://github.com/EnviDat/ckanext-restricted